# Show that $S_\lambda^2 - S_\lambda$ is semi-negative definite.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that the following matrix is semi-negative definite?
$$S_\lambda S_\lambda - S_\lambda$$

, where $S_\lambda = N\left(N^TN + \lambda \Omega\right)^{-1} N^T$. Assume that $N$ is a $n\times k$ full-rank matrix, $\lambda$ is some positive real number, and $\Omega$ is a diagonal matrix.

I can show that $N\left( N^T N \right)^{-1} N^T$ is idempotent, but not sure whether that can help or not.

Comment: It'd be more helpful to show $S_\lambda$ is self-transpose, hence diagonalizable.

Comment: @J.G. Then I got $x^T (D^2 - D) x$, still don't see why this has to be non-positive?

Comment: If you solve the problem for 1D $S_\lambda$ first, you'll discover one more detail that's pertinent to proving the general case.

Comment: @J.G. I'm afraid that I still don't get it. Are you saying that $x^2 (d^2 - d) \le 0$ for all $x$? I don't see why the eigenvalues of $S_\lambda$ has to be between $0$ and $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We wish to prove $N[(N^T N+\lambda\Omega)^{-1} N^T N (N^T N+\lambda\Omega)^{-1} - (N^T N+\lambda\Omega)^{-1}]N^T$ is negative-definite, i.e. that multiplying it by a row vector $A$ on the left and $A^T$ on the right gives $\le 0$. Since $N$ is full-rank, defining the row vector $B:=AN$ implies we can equivalently state the desired theorem as $(N^T N+\lambda\Omega)^{-1} N^T N (N^T N+\lambda\Omega)^{-1} - (N^T N+\lambda\Omega)^{-1}$ being negative-definite. Multiplying this by $B$ on the left and $B^T$ on the right and defining $C:=B(N^T N+\lambda\Omega)^{-1}$, the claim is equivalent to $C N^T N C^T - C (N^T N+\lambda\Omega) C^T = -\lambda C \Omega C^T\le 0$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Actually just realized that $\Omega$ is not diagonal but $\Omega_{ij} = \int \phi_i (x) \phi_j (x)\,dx$, but guess that still works, since $C\omega C^T$ will give us something like $\int (\sum c_i \phi_i)^2 \,dx$ which is apparently non-negative?

Comment: The trick is $\Omega$ should have non-negative eigenvalues, which is true of your example. However, general diagonal $\Omega$ are unsuitable.

Comment: Perhaps a trivial follow-up: How did you know that $\Omega$ have non-negative eigenvalues simply by knowing that its $ij$-th entry is $\int \phi_i \phi_j \,dx$?

Comment: @3x89g2 As you've noted, $C\Omega C^T$ is then $\ge 0$. For an eigenvector $C$, division by $C^2$ gives the eigenvalue.